# LogStream showing two totally different Azure web apps in same stream

Tags: logging, azure-web-app-service

I have two container-based web apps in my company's Azure organization. While they are under the same Subscription, they have different resources in different resource groups; they start from different Azure Container Registries; there is a Diagnostic Setting in each app sending HTTPAPI logs to a LogAnalytics workspace, different for each app.

Yet when I view the Log Stream page for *one* app at  `resource/subscriptions/`*subscriptionId*`/resourceGroups/`*resourceGroupName*`/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/`*websiteName*`/logStream`
I see logs from both web apps.

Is this normal?

Comment: Do you get the same result with "az webapp log tail --name <webSiteName> --resource-group <resourceGroupName>" ?

Comment: No, I don't -- I get only logs from the app specified. That's much better.  So if the UI page is unreliable at filtering to just my web app, I'll stop using it and use `az webapp log tail` instead. If you post that as an Answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to Log Stream UI in the Azure Portal, one might try Azure CLI `az log tail` to wit:

`az webapp log tail --name <webSiteName> --resource-group <resourceGroupName>`

As an aside, this sort of bleed through with Log Stream (and/or Application Insights) has been observed a couple times in the past and is certainly something Azure App Service support might like to know about.